# Routing to root path for differents domains on the same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to create a multi tenant on rails app.

How can I do to define the root path for each domain ?
I tried several solutions, but still have the same error :

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  domain_routes = {
    pdg: 'padog',
    bp: 'bopi'
  }

  domain_routes.each do |controller, domain|
    constraints(domain: domain) do
      root to: "#{controller}/home#index", as: "#{controller}_root"
      draw "#{controller}_routes".to_sym
    end
  end

end
```

bp is my principal domain

**#{controller}_routes.br** )

```
is empty
```

**EDIT**

I tried with namespace :

```
  domain_routes.each do |controller, domain|
    constraints(domain: domain) do
      namespace "#{controller}".to_sym, path: nil do
        root to: "home#index"
        draw "#{controller}_routes".to_sym
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: You want to create an app with multi-domain or multi-tenant by domain?

Comment: Multi tenant and multi domain 

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution for you is this gem `apartment`

And the part you need is [this one](https://github.com/rails-on-services/apartment?tab=readme-ov-file#switch-on-full-host-using-a-hash)

You can use `MD5` of the domain as a `tenant` and create a table `tenant` or something else to manage the tenants.
So You don't need to care about the routes. Just focus on the logic.

example:

```rb
# application.rb
module MyApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::HostHash, {'example.com' => 'example_tenant'}
  end
end
```

FYI, There are many options about the tenant for you. Just check it out
[gem link](https://github.com/rails-on-services/apartment)